# How to reformat a title, abandoning the format of the beamer theme?

Tags: formatting, titles

I use a beamer theme in my Latex, however I want to reformat the title while using the theme as well. Is it possible?And how to achieve this?
[image]

Like in this picture, I want to upward the title a little,so the title will not block the logo in the background. How to achieve this?My codes are listed as follows. 1.jpg is the background picture.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{Madrid}
}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{multirow}\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{CJK}\usepackage{hyperref}
\def\EE{\mathscr{E}}\def\FF{\mathscr{F}}
\def\IP{\mathbb{P}}\def\IE{\mathbb{E}}
\def\BB{\mathscr{B}}
\def\IR{\mathbb{R}}
\def\ss{\mathsf{s}}
\def\df{\mathrm{d}}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{1.jpg}}

\title{Regular Dirichlet Subspaces and Related Problems} 
\author{Jiangang Ying} % Your name
\institute[Fudan University] 
{
Fudan University \\ 
\medskip
\textit{jgying@fudan.edu.cn} 
}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not fully clear to us. What exactly do you mean by "upward the title"? Do you want to move it up  bit? And why don't you give your code so that we can find your solution with minimum hassle? If someone has to write your code first to find a solution, one will lose interest too quickly. And welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: @Masroor I'm sorry for my mistakes.And I have edited my question,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always design your own title page like you did for background. Here is an MWE. It's not perfect but it'll get you started.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation> {
    \usetheme{Madrid}
}


\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\setbeamertemplate{background}{\includegraphics[height=\paperheight]{fadedlogo}}

%% you can design your own title page
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows.blur}
\definecolor{MyBlue}{HTML}{D6D6F0}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \node[rectangle, draw=MyBlue,minimum height=1cm, minimum width=0.9\paperwidth, fill=MyBlue, rounded corners=1mm, blur shadow={shadow blur steps=5}] (title) at ([yshift=-1.5cm]current page.north){\Large Regular Dirichlet Subspaces and Related Problems};
    \node[below] (author) at ([yshift=-2cm]title.south) {\insertauthor}; 
    \node[below] (institute) at (author.south) {\tiny Fudan University}; 
    \node[below] (instituteid) at (institute.south) {   \tiny \textit{jgying@fudan.edu.cn}}; 
    \node[below] (date) at (instituteid.south) {\insertdate}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
%%

\title{Regular Dirichlet Subspaces and Related Problems} 
\author{Jiangang Ying} % Your name
\institute[Fudan University] 
{
    Fudan University \\ 
    \medskip
    \textit{jgying@fudan.edu.cn} 
}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}

    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage % Print the title page as the first slide
        \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I removed extra packages from your example which I did not need and I did not have your logo so I used a fake one. This produces the output:

[image: title page]